# Stenciljs Intercepting the removal of a component if the user does not confirm

Tags: stenciljs

I am developing a web app with stenciljs version 2.19.0.
In my application, each page is a stencil component.
I need to ensure that on certain pages, the exit (and therefore the component change) is intercepted with a modal that asks the user for confirmation if they really want to exit or not.
How can I achieve this? I have checked the lifecycle of components https://stenciljs.com/docs/component-lifecycle and I saw that the disconnected callback is called when the component has already been removed.
I don't see any other ways to intercept the exit from a component.

Is it possible to achieve the result I want using the stenciljs lifecycle?

Comment: Web Components are just regular classes; ``customElements.define("my-component", customElements.get("stencil-component"){ }`` will give you full control.

Comment: I don't understand your answer @Danny'365CSI'Engelman , what can I do with those methods?

Comment: You can create your own Web Component ``my-component`` which extends from the _existing_ Web Component ``stencil-component``. Its OOP, you can overload all methods. Like I did with Wordle, years ago: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/more-wordle-mordle-extending-josh-his-web-components-4li

Comment: What you're asking is usually done by the router. Which router are you using?

Comment: I've already done using my router (navigo router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve the result I want using the stenciljs lifecycle?

No - the Stencil lifecycle disconnected callback cannot be used to prevent removal of a component. This is a navigation issue - you want to stop navigation not component removal.

Comment: thank you. best answer. I can't do this using stencil lifecycle and I will use my router.